# smtp (gmail) fails in classic asp, but works in web service

Tags: .net, asp-classic, smtp, com+

I'm using .Net 4 c#, Windows Server 2008 R2, IIS 7 with the following code in my web service that I'm using to test sending an email.  It works.  I then use the same code in my classic asp app that calls .net c# via COM+ and it fails with

"System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: Failure sending mail. ---> System.Net.WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:587"

I have researched this for days and can't find anything that will help.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you.

```
        public static class Mail
        {
        public static void SendEmail(string subject, string body)
        {
        var fromAddress = new MailAddress("user@gmail.com", "From Name");
        var toAddress = new MailAddress("user@email.com", "To Name"); 
        const string fromPassword = "password";

        var smtp = new SmtpClient
        {
            Host = "smtp.gmail.com",
            Port = 587,
            EnableSsl = true,
            DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
            Credentials = new NetworkCredential(fromAddress.Address, fromPassword),
            Timeout = 20000
        };
        using (var message = new MailMessage(fromAddress, toAddress)
        {
            Subject = subject,
            Body = body
        })
        {
            smtp.Send(message);
        }
        }
    }
```

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow. are they on the same machine?

Answer (score 0):

If you really are using "user@gmail.com", I am guessing the server refuses to accept the credentials because this user is unknown. Try using an e-mail adress or username that actually exists on the server.